# JSON- Matching Keys to Values

Tags: python, json

Is there anyways to match the keys to the values in the following JSON file?

https://www.sec.gov/data/company_tickers_exchange.json

[Here is an Image of what I am looking at](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7mwX.png)

As you can see the keys are in the "fields" part and the values are in the "data" part. How would I be able to add say:

'cik; 320193, name: Apple Inc., ticker: AAPL, exchange: NASDAQ'

for every item in the data part?

Essentially what I am trying to do is to create a search function, in that if I search for "Apple Inc." it would return the CIK number. I want to be able to do that for any company.

How could I do that in python?

Comment: You have added the `python` tag, but you have added no code to your question.

Comment: "As you can see...", but we *can't* see. The information relevant to your question must be present *in* the question as text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with `pandas`, using [`df.to_dict('records')`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html):

```
import requests
import pandas

data = requests.get('https://www.sec.gov/data/company_tickers_exchange.json').json()
df = pd.DataFrame(data['data'], columns=data['fields'])
df.to_dict('records')
```

output:

```
[{'cik': 320193, 'name': 'Apple Inc.', 'ticker': 'AAPL', 'exchange': 'Nasdaq'}, {'cik': 789019, 'name': 'MICROSOFT CORP', 'ticker': 'MSFT', 'exchange': 'Nasdaq'}, ... ]
```